# Get data from an Asyn function and wait for the function to finish

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to get VSTS workitem detail via the below code

```
Task t = Task.Run(async () => await workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(int.Parse(relID)));
 t.Wait();
 var k = t.Result;
```

Here t.Result saying an error Task doesn't contain a definition for Result.

So how could get I get the result into var. The method from which I'm calling is not asynchronous.

Comment: `var bob = await workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync(int.Parse(relID)));`

Comment: to use await directly my function also should be async but its not

Comment: Hopefully the duplicate will help.

Comment: This scenario is called "sync over async", and it explicitly a **very very bad idea**. You can try `t.Wait()`, but: this is explicitly a very very bad thing to do

Comment: Apart from the bad idea of this setup. Your problem is you're specifically creating a variable of type `Task` (doesn't have a `Result` property), you're probably looking for `Task<TResult>` which inherits from `Task` but also has a `Result` property. So changing to `var t` should already fix it.